# JavaScript - how to identify or define THE "global" (super-global) for cross-platform use in strict mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, cross-platform

## global *reference*

I'm looking for a way to check if the "global" (super-global, -like "window") exists -and if not, to create it as such.

I've seen this done in some code on GitHub a few weeks ago, but, now that I need it, I can't find it anywhere. I may have miss-looked, but it was very short and all intelligent like on 1 (short) line - without `if`, and without using `var` (or `let`) - in global scope --> in strict mode.

I've been searching for 2 hours trying to find this and all I can find is countless references to "global variables" - which in this case, clearly not a "variable" as the super-global "window" (or in NodeJS "global") is not mutable.

The solution I currently have is not that great, but it works, sort-of:

```
"use strict";

if ('undefined' == typeof global)
{
    Object.defineProperty
    (
        window,'global',
        {
            writable:false,
            configurable:false,
            enumerable:false,
            value:window
        }
    );
}
```

So, if you try something like:

```
global = 'bite me!';
```

Then the behavior is as expected, it throws:

> **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'global' of...**

Which is good, -exactly as it should behave.

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to define it, because if I do something like:

```
console.log(global);
```

Then the console shows something like this:

> **Window {top: Window, ...**

Which tells me that it is not identified as "global" but as "window"; -which is all fair and well being a "circular"; however, I'm sure there's a better way to do this.

*Any input will be much appreciated, thanks*

Comment: `window = window || global || {some : new_object}`

Comment: @adeneo ::  in the browser, "window" already exists, so, it will just remain "window" in this case - and "global" will not be defined; but rather, it will throw because "global" is not defined. Also, if you do it that way in "strict mode" it will throw an error if "window" is not defined, like when used in NodeJS  ;)

Comment: Well, you can't overwrite the global, if it exists, it should be what it already is, shouldn't it?

Comment: Put var first? `var window = window || global || {some : new_object}`

Comment: That would technically be redeclaring, but should work. Another way would be to just check the runtime `var global = typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports ? global : typeof window !== undefined ? window : {some: 'other_object'};`

Comment: @evolutionxbox :: if in the browser platform, it will throw, I just tested and confirm: `Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined` .. same as comment above, you cannot reference undefined variables, unless you expect it to throw :D

Comment: @adeneo :: your second code comment above works! - just tested; however, it is mutable. After your code, when you do `global = "foo";` then global is "foo"; so, it can't work ;(  ..bummer .. I was all excited like.

Comment: Thanks for the input though, I really appreciate the help. - don't forget to "up-vote" posts if they are relevant and look more-or-less well-defined :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never thought this would actually work; but it does!
In global scope, after `use strict;` you can simply do this:

```
this.Main = this;
```

Now you can simply call and define things on `Main` as you would with `window` -or- `global`; and these new properties will exist in the global scope as expected.

After you've made the changes you want to this object; simply call:

```
Object.freeze(this.Main);  // makes it immutable
```

If you want to do it all in one go (for no valid reason whatsoever) you can do this:

```
Object.freeze(this.Main=this);  // it actually works!
```